# Getlocalday from Day to number

Tags: javascript, html

My school command is this:

The function-including getLocalDay Advocate Written below is returned the day of the week as integer.

It was 0 Sunday, Monday 1, Tuesday 2 etc ..

In some countries (including The Netherlands) is the first day of the week Monday. Make sure this function THAT THAT's how it works Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday as integers respectively 0 to 6 is returned. So 0 = Monday / Tuesday = 1/2 = Tuesday / Thursday = 3/4 = Friday / 5 = Saturday / Sunday 6 =

I got this

```
function getLocalDay(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();

    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Monday";
    weekday[1]="Tuesday";
    weekday[2]="Wednesday";
    weekday[3]="Thursday";
    weekday[4]="Friday";
    weekday[5]="Saturday";
    weekday[6]="Sunday";
    console.log("Today is " + weekday[3]);
    var d=new Date();
    console.log(d.getDay());
}
```

but i want to return numbers from that day.....

Comment: dont see anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to incorporated our solutions into the code on your own page. Here, I am showing a sample heading that contains a `span` that will be updated with the day number.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 
  // Get a reference to the <span> element on the page
  var label = document.getElementById("day");
  
  // Inject the answer from the function into it:
  label.textContent = getLocalDay(new Date());
  
});

function getLocalDay(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();

  var weekdays = ["Monday","Tuesday" ,"Wednesday" ,
                  "Thursday" ,"Friday" ,"Saturday" ,"Sunday" ];
    
  let dayNum = null;
  weekdays.forEach(function(d, index, arry){

    if(d === weekdays[day - 1]){
      dayNum = index;
    }
  });
    
  return dayNum;
}
```

```html
<h1>The day number for today is: <span id="day"></span></h1>
```

Comment: yeah but when i paste this im my script tab i dont get something showed

Comment: That's because the original snippet was set to show an answer in the developer tools console window. You need to take the information you get from Stack Overflow and incorporate it into your page code. We can't do all the work for you.

Comment: thank you so much, i started this year with my school on this and im not so good at javascript.. And my teacher is really bad too

Comment: Ok, Please also, up vote the answer by clicking the up arrow above the answer's score. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
function getLocalDay(date) {
  var dayIndex = date.getDay();
  var daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  return daysInWeek[dayIndex];
}
```

ES6 syntax

```
const getLocalDay = (date) => {
  const dayIndex = date.getDay();
  const daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  return daysInWeek[dayIndex];
}
```

---

Comment: @Dimitri what do you mean with "it doesn't show something"?

Comment: like i paste this in my script tab and when i open it in my browser its empty white page

Comment: @Dimitri You can test the code doing `getLocalDay(new Date())` it will return the string "Thursday"

Comment: That's working -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6bt58i9mrf356u/Screenshot%202016-12-08%2018.54.21.png?dl=0

Comment: @Dimitri To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. For more info check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235